# Этимология слова - "пловец"

Tags: этимология, история

Откуда берутся такие слова, как "пловец", т.е. слова исключения?
Отчего происходят и почему включаются в исключения? Ведь потом будет путаница в этимологии.
И ведь это загвоздка в будущем для, допустим, лингвиста, который будет изучать русский язык и происхождение слов лет эдак через 600-1000.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Большая часть исключений - традиционное написание, т.е. связано с историей языка.

Ярким примером исторического правописания в русском языке является правописание гласных после шипящих. Мы говорим жы, шы, но пишем жи, ши, потому что так произносились эти сочетания, когда согласные ж, ш были мягкими. И только три слова: жюри, брошюра, парашют, следуя транслитерационному принципу, пишутся через ю. В написании этих слов отражено и французское произношение и написание: жюри – jury, брошюра – brochure, парашют – parachute. Если бы эти слова были еще в древнерусском языке, то их написание целиком и полностью отражало бы традиционный принцип русской орфографии, так как ж, ш были мягкими. Но эти слова пришли к нам в XIX веке, когда ж, ш уже отвердели, и стали исключениями из правила.

Орфограмма" Е– и" в личных окончаниях глаголов.

В древнерусском языке глаголы делились на 4 тематических класса. К глаголам четвертого класса относились глаголы с нулевым суффиксом в основе настоящего времени и с суффиксом -и- в инфинитиве, а также с основой на ять  в инфинитиве, а после шипящих и йот на -а.Четвертый класс тематических глаголов относился ко второму спряжению:

обид -ти – обидиши;

вид -ти – видиши;

слыша-ти – слышиши.

Таким образом, глаголы слышать, видеть, ненавидеть, зависеть, терпеть, гнать, держать, дышать, обидеть, смотреть, вертеть изначально были глаголами второго спряжения. А современная формулировка правила «сделала» их исключениями.

Стелить. В современном русском языке имеются две формы этого глагола: стлать (1-е спряжение) и стелить (2-е спряжение). Но формы настоящего времени для обоих глаголов в литературном языке обычно употребляются общие: стелешь, стелет, стелют (то есть они изменяются по первому спряжению).
плыть.

Чередование корней плы-плав-плов зависит от существования дифтонгов в древнерусском языке.

Древнерусское и ст.-слав. – плоути (плыть).

Слово «плыть» широко применяется в русском языке с середины XI в.
Первоначально это слово значило путешествовать по воде (на лодке, плоту, корабле). Форма «плыву» появилась в XVII–XVIII вв. Интересно, что исследователи предполагают родство глагола «плыть» с латинским словом pluit (идет дождь, дождит) и с немецким flut (дождь, поток воды).

Производные: плавать, плыву, плывун.

Перед гласной дифтонг ou изменился в сочетание ов, сохранившееся в диалекте пл**ов**учий - нетонущий, держащийся на воде и в исключении"**плов-ьц-ь -** пловец" - тот, кто плавает. С изменением О в А возник глагол плавить - заставлять что-либо плыть (сплавлять), а из него -плавати - держаться на поверхности воды.Под ударением писали А, без ударения О.  В свое время появились сложносокращенные слова: плавкран, плавсредства с двумя ударениями. Если стали так говорить, то и писать слова стали с корнем плав (плавучий, плавун), а почва плывёт - это плывун. Так и была узаконена новая орфограмма, а историческое написание "пловец" и от него "пловчиха" стали исключениями.

А загвоздки в будущем быть не должно, если люди будущего будут изучать историю своего народа и его язык в развитии.

Answer (score 0):

**Орфография должна быть разумной и понятной для современников.** Можно очень долго рассказывать об исторической фонетике, вспоминать традиции письма, но объяснение выбора  гласной должно  соотноситься с современным состоянием языка. А или О, вот что интересует тех, кто говорит и пишет сегодня. **Почему нельзя проверить "пловец - плавать"?**

Всё дело в том, что данный корень уже имеет **два морфа**: плыть и плавать, позиция ударная в обоих случаях. **Плыть – основная форма**, плавать  – это  тоже плыть, но обозначает действие повторяющееся, совершающееся в различных направлениях, взад и вперёд. Пловец – это  скорее плывущий ("плывец"), а не плавающий ("плавец"), поэтому корень в нем ПЛОВ, а не ПЛАВ, чередование Ы/О.

**Что касается исключений вообще**, то их никто не придумывает специально, и обычно правило – это лишь удобная форма для подачи и запоминания информации. В теме чередующихся корней особенно много исключений, но в каждом случае есть **настоящая причина** для подобного решения орфограммы.  Ничем не объясненных и не оправданных исключений практически нет, и в этом особенность русского правописания. 
Орфографическая задача ставится, когда есть варианты решения, и тогда выбор становится необходимым. **Надо сказать, что большинство орфографических задач имеют оптимальное решение,** только логика их не всегда и не всем понятна и ясна.